# Is Android Installer (.apk file) supported in Tizen Os?

Tags: mobile, apk, store, tizen, android-runtime

Is [.apk file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) based installation supported on Tizen Os ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The native applications of both are entirely different, .apk for android coded in Java and .tpk for Tizen coded in C++. So its impossible to directly instal .apk files in Tizen.

But OpenMobile has created an application named ACL for Tizen which will run almost any android applications in Tizen platform.

First you will have to install the application in the Tizen device and you have to load the apk within the ACL application.

Comment: As far as I can tell the ACL app is no longer available in the Tizen Store. [It doesn't come up in the search results](http://www.tizenstore.com/search/searchResult.as?keyword=acl). I also found this independent post saying that OpenMobile, the company behind the ACL app permanently [ceased operating back in Jan 2018](https://www.tizenhelp.com/openmobile-company-closed-its-business-removed-all-apps-from-tizen-store/).

Answer (score 3):

No it is not supported directly, although there are some third-party emulators.

Tizen supports its own format `.tpk` for native and `.wgt`(which uses and extends W3C specifications) for Web Apps. Android uses `adb` for deployment, Tizen uses `sdb` for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but there is one compatibility layer for that. http://openmobile.co/pdf/Data_Sheet_ACL_for_Tizen_8.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Since android app is written by java, and Tizen OS is base on C/C++. it's not supported.