# Tizen App launch failing

Tags: c++, mobile, tizen

after a lot of trial and errors I could install app on Tizen emulator. But now app is not getting launched... When I see launch logs -

> Failed to open /opt/apps/Lerw5Kjy/bin/GeoMaker.exe :
>   /opt/apps/Lerw5Kjy/bin/GeoMaker.exe: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory.

But When see through Tizen IDE Connection Explorer, file is present on the said path. I'm not sure why it is saying so

Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure why somebody would down vote this question. It's been over 1 year now on SO and I know how to ask question.

Comment: It seems a legitimate question, I gave you an upvote so now you are not on negative, BTW I thing android tag is not proper. Tizen and Android are very different, android is linux kernel based, tizen has more than the kernel from linux and is backed by the Linux Foundation. 
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259544/is-android-installer-apk-file-support-tizen-os/14509525#14509525

Comment: You can test your app with samsung's Remote Test Lab http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there was an unsuccessful deployment also sometimes if you don't shutdown the emulator, the OS on the emulator's virtual machine gets corrupted.  Try to use the [Emulator Manager to create another    virtual machine](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/dev_env/emulator_manager.htm).

Then build again and deploy your application on the new emulator virtual machine, this should work.