# Is it possible to install an android app on Tizen OS device?

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I have an Android application. I wanted to install it on Tizen OS based device such as Samsung z1 or Samsung watch.

I don't know much about Tizen. Could you please explain if an existing Android app could be installed on Tizen OS device?

Comment: Try and see if your apk get installed. I doubt anyway, due different platforms and packages (apk, tpk).

Comment: Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259544/is-android-installer-apk-file-supported-in-tizen-os

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Open Mobile gives the option to other developers to convert their apk's to tpk's.

Have a look here http://pag.polarismobile.com/ which would be soon available for Tizen 2.3. PAG gives option to other developers to convert apk's to tpk's

It was already there for tizen 2.2 but since Samsung Z1 the only tizen based smartphone in market is tizen 2.3 based. Hence you won't be able to use the old PAG software.