# Google fit on Tizen OS

Tags: android, tizen, google-fit, tizen-native-app, sideloading

It has been 4 years since the below question was asked:
[Is it possible to install an android app on Tizen OS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648292/is-it-possible-to-install-an-android-app-on-tizen-os-device)

I have a samsung watch running Tizen 4.0 and I need to install google fit onto it. This is so that google fit (running on my phone already) can have access to the steps and heart rate sensor data from my watch.
This is because google fit is compatible with many apps and partners whereas samsung health is barely compatible with anything.

Does anyone know how to side load google fit onto a Tizen OS device (or even just enable google fit on the phone to access the wearable sensors)
I do not need to view the google fit app on my watch, although this would be a bonus.

Please keep answers very simple as I have no experience in developing for mobile devices.

Thank you very much in advance,

Anya

Comment: Hi Anya, were you able to find a way to sync your Samsung Galaxy steps with Vitality?

Comment: Nope, not yet. I've contacted all the websites I can think of with android/tizen developers. I'm fairly sure a brand new service needs to be written and I just don't have the skills to do it myself sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think it will not be supported: Using APK for Android on Tizen platform...

It is not simple issue - more than just using an java application...

Definitely, since Google fit needs Google Play Service library (A collection of Google-specific features) https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview,
Tizen Platform also needs to run Google Fit. It is more complicated than running a java application.

Comment: I realise this is going to be a very complex issue and that the google fit wearable app in its current state - designed for wear OS - is not going to be directly compatible with Tizen.
I think what is needed is for a developer who is comfortable with both google and tizen environments to adapt the google play services to be compatible with tizen. At that point the sensor data from the wearable could be transferred directly to google fit with little extra code.
Hopefully there's a developer out there who is willing and able to take this on - or has already done so.